# Pandas select last friday of each month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to figure out how to select the last Friday of a month with datetime in pandas for a database of daily dates.

```
df=df['Dates'].dt.month == 9 ]  # this gets me every September each year
df=df['Dates'].dt.week ???== 4 ???]  # I'm trying to get the last week of the month, but this doesn't work
df=df['Dates'].dt.dayofweek== 4 ]  # this gets me every Friday for every September, but I just want the last Friday
```

I read some questions where one can use "pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd", but have difficulty figuring out how to implement it.

If I do

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
Monthend(1) # this gives me the last day of the month
```

From there I think I would loop backwards until conditionally asking if the day is a friday or not.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to use the MonthEnd() function from pandas somehow. The other solutions use other libraries. I suspect there's a simpler solution though.

Comment: The duped answers aren't really using `pandas`. Try `df[df["Date"].dt.dayofweek.eq(4)].groupby(df["Date"].dt.month).last()` instead.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the right direction! group the data by each month, take all the days of the week, then take the last week! But unfortunately the code seems to not work with the groupby. It gets me 12 months, but I'm trying to get it for every month of every year.

Comment: Then `groupby` year as well: `df[df["Date"].dt.dayofweek.eq(4)].groupby([df["Date"].dt.month, df["Date"].dt.year]).last()`

Comment: @HenryYik Yes, i adjusted it a bit and it worked here: df[df["Date"].dt.dayofweek.eq(4)].groupby([stock["Date"].dt.year,stock["Date"].dt.month]).last() ! Not sure how to select that you got the right answer, but this is the solution with pure pandas.